# regex (javascript) allow \w but not a single specified word

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I've been banging my head against the wall and trying to google a solution for several hours with my "problem".

I need a javascript (html5 input) regex pattern, in a registration form which hasn't been submitted yet, which allows normally: `^[\w]+$`  but after a submit, if the page which processes the post finds that username is already been taken, takes user back to the registration form (which is now pre-filled with the values he/she typed).

This time that "username" input field should have a pattern which don't allow user to type that same username again, but everything else will do fine.

I've played around on http://regex101.com/#javascript and came up with 100% the opposite I wanted:

```
^(?=[\w]*)test(?=[\w]*)$
```

I've been testing my pattern with string:

- `abctestabc`
- `test`
- `dfea`
- `atest`
- `testa`

Regex I'm trying to obtain should match on everything else on my testing string, except for "test" and my pattern matches ONLY for that one.

Second pattern I came up with (which I shortly thought was what I wanted) was:

```
^(?:([\w]+test[\w]+)|([\w]+test|(test[\w]+)))$
```

..but didn't take long since I noticed that this only allows user to input:

- `*test`
- `*test*`
- `test*`

..but nothing without "test" included.

First time on form:

```
<input type="text" name="username" pattern="^[\w]+$" />
```

Secound time should be:

```
<input type="text" name="username" pattern="**PATTERN HERE**" value="test" />
```

So please Stackoverflow, Pimp my regex!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

user3548238, do you mean this?

```
^(?!test$)\w+$
```

This pattern will allow \w+, like before, but it will not allow "test".
This is accomplished with a [lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

Comment: LOL, that simple.. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @user3548238 Glad to hear it! If this is what you were looking for, kindly remember to click on the left to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: One more question: how do I modify this for email-address? Didn't seem to work with:  ^(?!test@test.com)$ ^(?!test\@test\.com)$

Comment: @user3548238 You said "one more question", but the question was blank.

Comment: Sorry, tried to come up with a new line, but this posted instead ;P

Comment: Yes, that could work. Just to clean it up, you could use \. in the parentheses instead of just ".", so that you specify an actual period as opposed to dot which means "any character".

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start pimping here ?

http://www.infotuts.com/live-username-availability-checker-and-password-strength-indicator-with-jquery-and-ajax/

[DEMO](http://www.infotuts.com/demo/username-checker-password-indicator/)

Comment: Because I'm using http://bootstrapvalidator.com and don't want live/ajax username/email checker, for security causes.

Comment: Nice little form for phishing usernames/emails ;P